# Material UI Autocomplete default value of empty string

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

When passing an empty string to Autocomplete, it throws a console warning saying that the value is invalid.

How do I get this warning to go away? It doesn't cause any issues, but it extremely annoying to have this thrown in the console for every rerender. The only way I seem to get it to not happen is setting the initial value for the field as null, which in my understanding is not what I should be putting as a default value of an input.

### Current Behavior

When passing the default value of empty string to the Autocomplete component, it throws a console warning that the value empty string is invalid.

[image: errorForGithub]

### Expected Behavior

If the value given to the Autocomplete is an empty string, there should be no warning or errors thrown.

### Steps to Reproduce

Here is a link to showcase the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-n0ijt

1) Pass an empty string to the value property of Autocomplete component.

Comment: Please update your question and remove all the non-relevant things. This is a copy&paste from the issue template of the material-ui github page. Please don't use this here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Seemed like a good way to show what I have done and what the issue I'm experiencing is.

Comment: As mentioned - keep only the relevant data (the structure is not relevant, the environment is not relevant, etc...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved it handling the case in which the input string is empty (you are not doing that). 3 things are needed in your Sandbox:

1. line 17, inside the `getOptionSelected`, you must return true when the value is the empty string; in this way React selects one option and the warning disappears.
2. line 14, modify the `getOptionLabel`, handling the case of the empty string. I would do the following:

```
getOptionLabel={option => option.title ? option.title : ''}
```

So in case the option has a title, it returns a title, otherwise it returns an empty string that is visualized.

3. Finally, modify the `onChange` to handle the empty string, in this way

```
onChange={(e, selectedObject) => {
    if (selectedObject !== null)
        setValue(selectedObject)
}}
```

Overall:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function FreeSoloCreateOption() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      id="empty-string-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title ? option.title : ''}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
        //nothing that is put in here will cause the warning to go away
        if (value === "") {
          return true;
        } else if (value === option) {
          return true;
        }
      }}
      onChange={(e, selectedObject) => {
        if (selectedObject !== null)
            setValue(selectedObject)
      }}
      renderOption={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Default Value of Empty String"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For my case just the label formator was causing the issue. Updated it to `getOptionLabel={(option) => (option && option.label)? option.label: ""}`

Comment: This is what I do:

`getOptionLabel={option => option?.title || ''}`

`getOptionSelected={(option, value) => value === '' || option.id === value.id}`

Comment: I have tried the above solution. When component initialising, all the options in dropdown are in selected mode.Can I get the fix for that ?

Comment: This one helped me a lot , i was in the exact same situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 41):

you can use `null` as initial state and that might achieve what you're trying

`value={data.value || null}`

if you set it to undefined it complains about controlled component, this way I don't get an error even after I use the Autocomplete

Comment: doing `const val = [val, setVal] = useState(null);` worked perfectly when I did `value={val}`

Comment: In MUI 5+, either this or `isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => value === option || value === ''} ` solution can be used

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It works (at least in my use-case) -- it silences the annoying complaint. It does not require passing other more complicated props to Autocomplete. Last, but not least, it has the most upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

One simple change is to filter the initial reset out

```
onChange={(event, newValue, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'reset' && newValue === '') {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else {
        setValue(newValue);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Autocomplete...

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
    // Accept empty string
    if(value === option || value === "") { return true; }
}}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. if the value is `""` it will return true that every option is selected... It works if you reverse the lazy evaluation... `if(value === option || value === "" ) { return true; }`

Comment: user10233170 THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Autocomplete className={styles['vacation-list-status']}
                        id="vacation-list-status"
                        options={vacationStatus}
                        getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                          handleVacationStatus( 
                              newValue ? newValue.value : null
                          );
                        }}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                           <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label={t('status')}
                           />
                        )}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const options = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"];

const Demo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const handleReset = () => {
    setValue(null);
  };
  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        freeSolo
        value={value}
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Select an option..." />
        )}
      />
      <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
      <div>The current value is: {value}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Demo;
```

If you have multiple autocomplete and want to reset you can do this additionally, Pass value={value || []}. After reset u will have empty value