# MUI Autocomplete highlights all items if value is a empty string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I have following problem.

I try to create a custom Autocomplete Component for filtering purposes.

At some point I ran into following Warning.

```
   MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `""`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

In order to fix the warning I have added the "isOptionEqualToValue" prop.

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
    return value === option || value === undefined || value === "";
  }}
```

But know all of the options are selected(highlighted) if value is "". [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlr7O.png)

Here is my whole Component

```
import { Autocomplete, SxProps, TextField, Theme, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Clear } from "@mui/icons-material";

interface AusgabefeldProps {
  getFilterValue: () => unknown;
  setFilterValue: (updater: any) => void;
  options: String[];
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
}

export function AutocompleteFilterColumnSimpleData(props: AusgabefeldProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [toolTipIsOpen, setToolTipIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Tooltip
      title="Filter zurücksetzen"
      arrow
      placement="right"
      open={toolTipIsOpen}
      PopperProps={{
        sx: {
          "& .MuiTooltip-tooltip": {
            marginLeft: "0px !important",
            marginTop: "5px",
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        inputValue={value}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
          return value === option || value === undefined || value === "";
        }}
        sx={{
          "& .MuiInputBase-input ": { height: "1.2rem" },
          "& .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator ": {
            visibility: "visible",
            padding: "0px",
            height: "28px",
            width: "28px",
          },
          "& .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator:hover ": {
            backgroundColor: value ? "" : "transparent",
          },
          "& .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator:active ": {
            pointerEvents: value ? "auto" : "none",
          },
        }}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(!newValue ? "" : (newValue as string));
          props.setFilterValue(!newValue ? undefined : (newValue as string));
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setValue(event.target.value);
            }}
            style={{ paddingTop: "5px" }}
            variant={"outlined"}
          />
        )}
        options={props.options}
        clearIcon={
          <Clear
            sx={{
              color: value ? "" : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)",
              cursor: value ? "" : "text",
            }}
            onMouseEnter={() => setToolTipIsOpen(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setToolTipIsOpen(false)}
          />
        }
        clearText={""}
        closeText={""}
        openText={""}
      />
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

**Expected Value**
No warning and no list items are highlighted if value is a empty string

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219164/material-ui-autocomplete-default-value-of-empty-string